# Close all child when parent was close

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Is there anyway to make close all child when parent close in Jquery UI Accordion

[image]

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is too vague and does not include a proper example. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example